# Unable to start MOSS 2007 services on Virtual machine (Virtual PC)

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp.net, sharepoint-2007, virtual-machines

I am unable to start the MOSS 2007 services after everything has been installed perfectly. Any idea of what is going wrong? I have also installed SQL Server 2005 (Dev edition).

Comment: You might want to specify what exactly goes wrong (an error message, anything useful in the event logs...)

Comment: Which services?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is status of services on server:
Central Administration > Operations > Services on Server**

Document Conversions Launcher Service    Stopped
Document Conversions Load Balancer Service    Stopped
Excel Calculation Services  Required on Farm, not running Stopped
Office SharePoint Server Search  Required on Farm, not running Stopped
Windows SharePoint Services Incoming E-Mail    Started 
Windows SharePoint Services Search  Required on Farm, not running Stopped
Windows SharePoint Services Web Application

Comment: You should have updated your question since it does not relate to answer in any way